# Parameterized Queries PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a PDO parameterized query with a LIKE statement in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583336/how-do-i-create-a-pdo-parameterized-query-with-a-like-statement-in-php)
>   [PHP PDO prepared statement — mysql LIKE query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786436/php-pdo-prepared-statement-mysql-like-query)

I'm trying to make a search engine for my website, and right now I'm just trying to make sure the connection is all and well.  Here is my code thus far:

*EDITED CODE (Still doesn't work, but here's where I'm at with the suggestions thus far):*

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE name LIKE ? ORDER BY bid DESC");
$stmt->bindParam(1, "%{$_GET['s']}%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

I tried to see if the different methods of `execute` would do anything, but regardless of which way above I write it, I get the same result, nothing.  I want the `%` wildcard in there so it does it'll search anywhere in `name`.  On that note, am I using it correctly?  The thing that confuses me most is when I type in the exact same query into PHPMyAdmin, the query runs through fine, so my guess is that I'm screwing up the PDO somewhere.

---

EDIT: PHPMyAdmin Query:

> SELECT * 
>   FROM table_1
>   WHERE name LIKE  '%Test%'
>   ORDER BY bid DESC 
>   LIMIT 0 , 30

This returns 1 result, as it is expected to.  What is different about my code and this query? :/

Comment: @Matt Regarding your edit: my edited answer should explain it.

Comment: @Matt No, now you added quotes around the `?`. Don't. I just added the correct query to my answer for increased clarity.

Comment: Ya i realized I had that in the post, the code didn't; still doesn't work.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't quote parameters in prepared statements. If you do, it's a string, not a parameter (the `':search'` in the commented portion of the sample code won't work, because it will be parsed as a string with the value ":search", not a parameter named "search"). Also, only change the sample code when it doesn't properly illustrate your question. "I don't know why my code isn't working." isn't a question. "Why isn't my code working?" is too vague to be useful.

Comment: @Matt Well that's weird, because that's exactly the example used in the doc http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php#example-943

Comment: That's why I'm on here, because I'm totally stumped :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really understand what your question is, but I'm guessing you don't know how to add the `%`? If so, try this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE name LIKE ? ORDER BY bid DESC");
$stmt->bindValue(1, "%{$_GET['s']}%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmnt->execute();
// fetch and win! :-)
```

**A little explanation:**
PDO will quote and escape the parameter `?` appropriately. This means, that if you are binding `hello`, PDO will substitute `?` with `'hello'` (note the quotes). Therefore, in order to have the `%` inside the quotes, you will have to add them to what is binded, in this case `$_GET['s']`.

Comment: Turns out it was working; the case sensitivity of the variables in my display table were the reason it wasn't working, not the query connection...