# Mysql search query with special character

Tags: php, mysql

If i have a variable like

```
   $volume = 'IV, no. 33';
   $query = "Select post_id FROM wp_postmeta  where meta_value LIKE ".$volume." 

It show error.
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' no. 33

So what is the correct way for search with special characte.

Comment: You have to put quotes around that string value. `LIKE '".$query->meta_value."'`

Comment: explain this term "search with special character" with an example.

Comment: Try: `"Select post_id FROM wp_postmeta  where meta_value LIKE "'".$volume."'"`

Comment: Consider using parametrized queries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869676/parameterized-queries-php-mysql

Comment: Take care of SQL-injection, you can do this with parametrized queries (recommended) or with escaping the string input.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put quotes around your string value

```
$volume = 'IV, no. 33';
 $query = "Select post_id FROM wp_postmeta  where meta_value LIKE ".$volume."
```

Should be

```
$volume = 'IV, no. 33';
$query = "Select post_id FROM wp_postmeta  where meta_value LIKE '".$volume."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot quotes

```
$query = "Select post_id FROM wp_postmeta  where meta_value LIKE '".$volume."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
 $volume = 'IV, no. 33';
 $query = "Select post_id FROM wp_postmeta  where meta_value LIKE '".$volume."'";
```

Use the single quota to tell the query that it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

### Use single quote

```
LIKE ".$volume."
```

to

```
LIKE '".$volume."'
```