# Clean form data to be used in SQL LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I clean post data using mysqli_real_escape_string. Should I also, then, apply addcslashes() to a variable that is used in an SQL LIKE clause?

[I understand that using prepared statements would probably negate this discussion.]

Comment: Your comment about prepared statement is a good one. You should switch to those right away. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786436/php-pdo-prepared-statement-mysql-like-query

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping MySQL wild cards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683746/escaping-mysql-wild-cards) - but the given `str_replace` based solution does not look right to me. Just noting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot use prepared statements (always a good option) - as far as I know it is best to escape the mysql like wildcards aswell:

```
addcslashes($param, '%_');
```

Comment: Thanks - just what I was looking for! [People here are very keen on prepared statements. I understand this.. but the constant repetition sometimes distracts from the original question.]