# prepared statement and binding parameters conflict

Tags: php, prepared-statement

Please look at the PHP code:

```
$val = $_POST['name']; 
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init(); 
$stmt->prepare("SELECT id, name, email FROM some_table WHERE name LIKE ?%"); 
$stmt->bind_param('s', $val); 
$stmt->execute();
```

When I run this query; I get the following error:
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt

What is wrong here?

Comment: You're not checking the return values; I'd also suggest using mysqli_error to see what the actual error is. At a guess, I'd say that `?%` in the query is wrong, and that the `%` should be part of `$val`

Comment: The `%` is part of the value that is bound, not part of the prepared query

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786436/php-pdo-prepared-statement-mysql-like-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it as below:

```
$val = $_POST['name'] . '%'; 
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init(); 
$stmt->prepare("SELECT id, name, email FROM some_table WHERE name LIKE ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param('s', $val);
$stmt->execute();
```

Basically, the prepared stmt should still have only the placeholder '?', while your variable should have the wildcard '%' at end

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `?` should either stay as a placeholder in SQL expression or - again, as a placeholder, be used in SQL function(s). So you have two options here: just add `%` to a supplied value, like this:

```
$val = $_POST['name'] . '%';
$stmt->prepare("SELECT id, name, email FROM some_table 
  WHERE name LIKE ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param('s', $val);
```

... or leave the value as is, modifying SQL instead:

```
$stmt->prepare("SELECT id, name, email FROM some_table 
  WHERE name LIKE CONCAT(?, '%')"); 
$stmt->bind_param('s', $val);
```

Comment: When I did what you mentioned, here is the error I received: Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

Comment: Updated the answer: it's bindParam, not bindValue, so the value should be passed by reference indeed.